# Pass element into function WITHOUT anonymous function in jquery

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

As the title, is there a way to pass an element into a function without using an anonymous function?

Or in other words:

I know I can pass element into function as follows:

```
function fakeFunction(elementReceived){
    elementReceived.hide();
}
$(".class-x").each(function(){
    fakeFunction($(this));
});
```

which is not acceptable as I am required to prevent using anonymous function due to some problem in testing.

So I write something like this:

```
function fakeFunction(){
    $(this).hide();
}
$(".class-x").each(fakeFunction);
```

This is better but the readability is decreased, as the function in the actual code is very far away from the calling line and using $(this) directly is confusing.

I was told (and was requested to investigate) that something like the following should be possible:

```
function fakeFunction(elementReceived){
    elementReceived.hide();
}
$(".class-x").each(fakeFunction, $(this));
```

but the $(this) in the above code passed the whole document instead..... What should be the proper way to write it?

Comment: If the testing process leads you to add hacks to avoid perfectly valid (and recommended) patterns with jQuery, I would suggest to also review the testing process ...

Comment: While your suggestion is good, it is not something that can be easily done in a short period of time. Changing my code will be a better option at this moment.

Comment: I know. Just voicing it.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the documentation for `each`](http://api.jquery.com/each), you'll see that the second argument to the function is the element (e.g., the same as `this`). So:

```
function fakeFunction(index, element){
    $(element).hide();
}
$(".class-x").each(fakeFunction);
```

*(Of course, in this particular case, you could just do `$(".class-x").hide();`, but I assume `fakeFunction` actually does something else.)*

Comment: While this improves readability and solve my problem..... Is there really no way to pass element directly? That second argument is actually string and still require $(element).hide(); instead of element.hide(); (but at this point, it is just my curiosity instead of a problem now)

Comment: @user1273587: The second argument *isn't* a string, it's a DOM element. You just use `$()` to wrap it in a jQuery instance to get access to the jQuery stuff. You could (for instance) do `element.style.display = "none";` to hide it without using jQuery.